# What does the command "Sudo apt-get install *" do?

Tags: linux

I'm just wondering what would happen if you typed in the titular command in a terminal, but not curious enough to try it. Does anyone actually know?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing particularly interesting. `*` is expanded by the shell as a list of all the filenames in your current directory, and chances are that most of those will not be valid package names.

If you did pass `apt-get install` a list of all available packages, installing them all would fail (after spending quite a while thinking about dependencies), because at least some of those packages will conflict with each other.

Comment: apt-get uses regular expressions, so the actual way to do this would be `apt-get install .\*`